# SSH link terminates every 20 seconds

Tags: ssh, router

I am using a 3rd party software to get an SSH link into my device (remot3.it). I use Putty to SSH. All my other devices work but one device frequently loses SSH connection within 20 seconds but always remains online (I just can't successfully stay logged in). Each device is on a separate network so I am assuming the router/firewall configuration is causing this. I would appreciate an explanation of what could possibly cause this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Does the connection terminate if there is data going back/forth between the client and the server?  For example, if you run `top`, does the connection still terminate after 20 seconds?

Comment: error is: "connection reset by peer"

Comment: @mti2935 the connection terminates whether data is transferred or not. Seems like its on a very short dhcp lease or something. But I don't want to make assumptions since this area is very new to me

Comment: Are you seeing anything useful in the server logs (e.g.  /var/log/messages or /var/log/auth.log )?

Comment: Really a question for Server Fault, I'm voting to move it there.

Comment: have you tested to change "TCPKeepAlive" directive in ssh configuration from "yes" to "no" ?

Comment: @mti2935 unable to view logs as connection not allowing me to SSH currently but I see device is online

Comment: @ZarehK no I have not tested that. My error is "Connection reset by peer". Doesn't that mean the router/firewall on the network is the issue?